# Magento2: Change store view in product list of admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, product-list, store-view

Is it possible to change the store view in the product list of admin panel?

Currently Magento 2 lists product names as saved in one particular store view and that makes things difficult because that language is not not understood by admins. Magento somehow overrides the default value (website level) of the product name with product name taken from one of the store views.

UPDATE:
You can select the default store view for Store level in Stores -> All Stores. There is still missing a store view changer in Catalog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a filter for product list in admin. When you select the store view to the filter it shows the data saved for that store view.